# Anchura de video no funciona

Tags: html, css

https://www.dropbox.com/s/f6lo2h6fxgprm70/que_es.mp4?dl=0

que trato de modificarle el width y crece pero hasta el height crece no se que podria hacer o si lo estoy haciendo mal, ejemplo esta asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora solo modificando el width crece como un todo y no solo el width 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CSS

```
@font-face {
  font-family: MyriadPro-Regular;
  src: url("../fonts/MyriadPro-Regular.otf") format("opentype");
}

/* mobile */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  /**/
  body {
    overflow: visible !important;
  }
  body #box-container {
    height: 93vh !important;
    padding-top: 9vh !important;
  }
  body #footer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2vh !important;
    width: 100vw;
    text-align: right !important;
    padding: 0;
    height: 7vh !important;
  }
  body #footer .img-rs {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10%;
  }
  body #footer .img-rs:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  body #footer #terminos-y-condiciones {
    display: none;
    margin-top: 1vh;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
  body #footer #terminos-y-condiciones h4 {
    color: white;
  }
  body #modal {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10000;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
  body #modal .container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5vh !important;
    left: 10vw !important;
    width: 80vw !important;
    height: 90vh !important;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  body #modal .container img#boton-cerrar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    width: 8% !important;
  }
  body #modal .container img#boton-cerrar:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  body #modal .container #box-modal {
    height: 100%;
  }
  body #modal .container #box-modal #box-modal-titulo {
    text-align: center;
    height: 10%;
  }
  body #modal .container #box-modal #box-modal-titulo h1 {
    display: initial !important;
    font-size: 9vw;
  }
  body #modal .container #box-modal #box-modal-info {
    padding-top: 10%;
    text-align: center !important;
    height: 40%;
  }
  body #modal .container #box-modal #box-modal-info video {
    width: 100% !important;
    float: initial !important;
    margin-right: 1vw;
    margin-bottom: 1vh !important;
  }
  body #modal .container #box-modal #box-modal-info h1 {
    display: none !important;
  }
  body #modal .container #box-modal #box-modal-info p {
    font-size: 4vw !important;
    text-align: justify !important;
  }
  body #modal-bienvenido .container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 15vh !important;
    left: 10vw !important;
    width: 80vw !important;
    height: 70vh !important;
  }
  body #modal-bienvenido .container img#boton-cerrar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    width: 8% !important;
  }
  body #modal-bienvenido .container img#boton-cerrar:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  body #modal-bienvenido .container #box-modal {
    height: 100%;
  }
  body #modal-bienvenido .container #box-modal #box-modal-titulo {
    text-align: center;
    height: 35% !important;
  }
  body #modal-bienvenido .container #box-modal #box-modal-info {
    padding-top: 10%;
    text-align: justify;
    height: 55% !important;
  }
  body #modal-bienvenido .container #box-modal #box-modal-info p {
    font-size: 4vw !important;
  }
  body #modal-init {
    padding-top: 5%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-left: 24%;
  }
  body #modal-init img#boton-cerrar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 8px;
    width: 10%;
  }
  #modal-header-init {
    border-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .modal .modal-popout-bg {
    height: 105%;
    padding-top: 3%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 270%;
  }
  .titulo-modal {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .titulo-modal h3 {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    margin-top: -5%;
  }
  #modal_init_content {
    text-align: justify;
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 12%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    color: black;
  }
}

/* tablet */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  /**/
  body #box-container {
    height: 88vh;
    padding-top: 12vh !important;
  }
  body #modal {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10000;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
  body #modal .container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15vh !important;
    left: 10vw !important;
    width: 80vw !important;
    height: 70vh !important;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  body #modal .container img#boton-cerrar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    width: 6% !important;
  }
  body #modal .container img#boton-cerrar:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  body #modal .container #box-modal {
    height: 100%;
  }
  body #modal .container #box-modal #box-modal-titulo {
    text-align: center;
  }
  body #modal .container #box-modal #box-modal-titulo h1 {
    display: initial !important;
    font-size: 5vw;
  }
  body #modal .container #box-modal #box-modal-info {
    padding-top: 5%;
    text-align: center !important;
    height: 70% !important;
  }
  body #modal .container #box-modal #box-modal-info video {
    width: 50% !important;
    margin-right: 1vw;
    margin-bottom: 1vh !important;
  }
  body #modal .container #box-modal #box-modal-info h1 {
    display: none !important;
  }
  body #modal .container #box-modal #box-modal-info p {
    font-size: 3vw !important;
    text-align: justify !important;
  }
  body #modal-bienvenido .container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20vh !important;
    left: 15vw !important;
    width: 70vw !important;
    height: 60vh !important;
  }
  body #modal-bienvenido .container img#boton-cerrar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    width: 5%;
  }
  body #modal-bienvenido .container img#boton-cerrar:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  body #modal-bienvenido .container #box-modal {
    height: 100%;
  }
  body #modal-bienvenido .container #box-modal #box-modal-titulo {
    text-align: center;
    height: 20% !important;
  }
  body #modal-bienvenido .container #box-modal #box-modal-info {
    padding-top: 10%;
    text-align: justify;
    height: 70% !important;
  }
  body #modal-bienvenido .container #box-modal #box-modal-info p {
    font-size: 2.5vw !important;
  }
  body #modal-init {
    padding-top: 5%;
  }
  body #modal-init img#boton-cerrar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 8px;
    width: 10%;
  }
  #modal-header-init {
    border-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .modal .modal-popout-bg {
    height: 105%;
    padding-top: 3%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 150%;
  }
  .titulo-modal {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .titulo-modal h3 {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
  }
  #modal_init_content {
    text-align: justify;
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 12%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    color: black;
  }
}

/* desktop */
html {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, #c23030, #750c0d);
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: "MyriadPro-Regular";
}

body #box-container {
  height: 93vh;
  padding-top: 5vh;
}

body #box-container #box-logo-y-formulario #box-logo img {
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
}

body #box-container #box-logo-y-formulario #box-formulario form .form-group {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

body #box-container #box-logo-y-formulario #box-formulario form .form-group label.telefonos {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: -25px;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

body #box-container #box-logo-y-formulario #box-formulario form .form-group label.comuna {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: -40px;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

body #box-container #box-logo-y-formulario #box-formulario form .form-group label.error {
  color: #b7b7b7;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

body #box-container #box-logo-y-formulario #box-formulario form .form-group .form-control::placeholder {
  color: #b7b7b7;
}

body #box-container #box-logo-y-formulario #box-formulario form .form-group .form-control {
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: none;
  border-color: #e7b336;
  color: white;
}

body #box-container #box-logo-y-formulario #box-formulario form .form-group button {
  padding: 5px 19px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #e7b336;
  color: #750c0d;
}

body #box-container #box-logo-y-formulario #box-formulario form .form-group .bootstrap-select button {
  background: none;
  color: white;
  border-color: #e7b336;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

body #box-container #box-logo-y-formulario #box-formulario form .form-group .bootstrap-select .dropdown-menu li a {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

body #box-container #box-logo-y-formulario #box-formulario form .form-group .bootstrap-select .dropdown-menu .active a {
  background-color: #c23030;
}

body #box-container #box-logo-y-formulario #box-formulario form .form-group .bootstrap-select .dropdown-menu .bs-searchbox .form-control {
  color: #333;
}

body #box-container #box-logo-y-formulario #box-formulario form #error {
  opacity: 0;
  color: #882a28;
  background-color: #edc0c0;
  padding: 5px 19px;
}

body #box-container #box-informativo {
  text-align: center;
}

body #box-container #box-informativo #info {
  padding: 5px 19px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #e7b336;
  color: #750c0d;
}

body #footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  height: 7vh;
}

body #footer .img-rs {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;
}

body #footer .img-rs:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

body #footer #terminos-y-condiciones {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 1vh;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

body #footer #terminos-y-condiciones h4 {
  color: white;
}

body #modal {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10000;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

body #modal .container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10vh;
  left: 15vw;
  width: 70vw;
  height: 80vh;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

body #modal .container img#boton-cerrar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  width: 3%;
}

body #modal .container img#boton-cerrar:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

body #modal .container #box-modal {
  height: 100%;
}

body #modal .container #box-modal #box-modal-titulo {
  text-align: center;
  height: 10%;
}

body #modal .container #box-modal #box-modal-titulo div {
  margin-top: 2vh;
}

body #modal .container #box-modal #box-modal-titulo div h1 {
  display: none;
}

body #modal .container #box-modal #box-modal-info {
  padding-top: 5%;
  text-align: justify;
  height: 40%;
}

body #modal .container #box-modal #box-modal-info video {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 4vw;
}

body #modal .container #box-modal #box-modal-info h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

body #modal .container #box-modal #box-modal-info p {
  font-size: 1.3vw;
}

body #modal-bienvenido {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10000;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

body #modal-bienvenido .container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 16vh;
  left: 34vw;
  width: 33vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 16px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 7px;
  border-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

body #modal-bienvenido .container img#boton-cerrar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  width: 5%;
}

body #modal-bienvenido .container img#boton-cerrar:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

body #modal-bienvenido .container #box-modal {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}

body #modal-bienvenido .container #box-modal #box-modal-titulo {
  text-align: center;
  height: 10%;
}

body #modal-bienvenido .container #box-modal #box-modal-info {
  padding-top: 10%;
  text-align: justify;
  height: 80%;
}

body #modal-bienvenido .container #box-modal #box-modal-info p {
  font-size: 1.5vw;
}

body #modal-init {
  height: 90%;
  width: 20%;
  padding-top: 5%;
}

body #modal-init img#boton-cerrar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  width: 10%;
}

body #modal-header-init {
  border-bottom: 0px;
}

body .modal .modal-popout-bg {
  height: 90%;
  padding-top: 7%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-color: rgba(197, 42, 42, 0.45);
}

body .modal-content {
  border: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

body .titulo-modal {
  text-align: center;
}

body .titulo-modal h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}

body #modal_init_content {
  text-align: justify;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-left: 12%;
  padding-right: 12%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
  color: black;
}

body #linea {
  size: 5px;
  width: 99%;
}

body #img-modal-init {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

body #reg-mod {
  text-align: justify;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-left: 12%;
  padding-right: 12%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
  color: black;
}

body #img-modal-welcome {
  width: 9%;
}

body #img-modal-welcome-hand {
  width: 7%;
  position: absolute;
}

body #img-modal-welcome2 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  right: 0px;
  width: 60%;
}

body #box-modal-titulo p {
  padding: 4%;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

body #title-welcome {
  padding-top: 12%;
}

body #container-modal-wel {
  width: 60%;
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scale=no"/>
    <meta name="description" content=""/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./libs/bootstrap-select/css/bootstrap-select.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css"/>
    <script src="./libs/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./libs/bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./libs/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <title>Naw</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" id="box-container">
      <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" id="box-logo-y-formulario">
        <div class="row" id="box-logo">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12"><img class="img-responsive" src="./images/logos/logo.png" alt="Naw Logo"/></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="box-formulario">
          <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-0 col-md-12 col-md-offset-0">
            <form id="formu">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nombre_apellido" placeholder="Nombre / Apellido"/>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group box-telefono">
                <label class="telefonos" for="telefono">+56 9</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="telefono" type="text" name="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono"/>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group box-telefono">
                <label class="telefonos" for="confirmar-telefono">+56 9</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="confirmar-telefono" type="text" name="confirmar_telefono" placeholder="Confirme su Teléfono"/>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Mail"/>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="comuna" for="comuna">Comuna</label>
                <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="comuna" name="comuna" data-live-search="true">
                  <option value="cerrillos">cerrillos</option>
                  <option value="cerro navia">cerro navia</option>
                  <option value="conchalí">conchalí</option>
                  <option value="el bosque">el bosque</option>
                  <option value="estación central">estación central</option>
                  <option value="huechuraba">huechuraba</option>
                  <option value="independencia">independencia</option>
                  <option value="la cisterna">la cisterna</option>
                  <option value="la florida">la florida</option>
                  <option value="la pintana">la pintana</option>
                  <option value="la granja">la granja</option>
                  <option value="la reina">la reina</option>
                  <option value="las condes">las condes</option>
                  <option value="lo barnechea">lo barnechea</option>
                  <option value="lo espejo">lo espejo</option>
                  <option value="lo prado">lo prado</option>
                  <option value="macul">macul</option>
                  <option value="maipú">maipú</option>
                  <option value="ñuñoa">ñuñoa</option>
                  <option value="padre hurtado">padre hurtado</option>
                  <option value="pedro aguirre cerda">pedro aguirre cerda</option>
                  <option value="peñálolén">peñálolén</option>
                  <option value="pirque">pirque</option>
                  <option value="providencia">providencia</option>
                  <option value="puente alto">puente alto</option>
                  <option value="pudahuel">pudahuel</option>
                  <option value="quilicura">quilicura</option>
                  <option value="quinta normal">quinta normal</option>
                  <option value="recoleta">recoleta</option>
                  <option value="renca">renca</option>
                  <option value="san bernardo">san bernardo</option>
                  <option value="san joaquín">san joaquín</option>
                  <option value="san josé de maipú">san josé de maipú</option>
                  <option value="san miguel">san miguel</option>
                  <option value="san ramón">san ramón</option>
                  <option value="santiago">santiago</option>
                  <option value="vitacura">vitacura</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9 alert alert-danger" id="error" role="alert">
                <p>Mensaje de error</p>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
                <button class="btn" type="submit">Recibir Ofertas</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="box-informativo">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <button class="btn" id="info" data-target="#modal">¿Qué es Naw?</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="footer">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4"><img class="img-responsive img-rs" src="./images/logos/mail.png" alt="" data-href="contacto@naw.cl" data-type="mail"/><img class="img-responsive img-rs" src="./images/logos/fb.png" alt="" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/NAW-133950147218870/" data-type="link"/><img class="img-responsive img-rs" src="./images/logos/insta.png" alt="" data-href="https://www.instagram.com/naw_cl/" data-type="link"/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="modal">
      <div class="container"><img id="boton-cerrar" src="./images/logos/cerrar.png" alt="" data-target="#modal"/>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" id="box-modal">
          <div class="row" id="box-modal-titulo">
            <!-- <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12"> yo--> 
              <h1>¿Qué es Naw?</h1>
            <!-- </div> -->
          </div>
          <div class="row" id="box-modal-info">
              <video src="./video/que_es.mp4" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">Tu navegador no implementa el elemento <code>video</code>.</video>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
              <!-- <video src="./video/que_es.mp4" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">Tu navegador no implementa el elemento <code>video</code>.</video> -->
              <!-- <h1>¿Qué es Naw?</h1> -->
              <!-- <p>
                NAW es una plataforma gratuita, creada para que recibas ofertas exclusivas de marcas, productos y servicios directamente a tu Whatsapp.
                Para ser parte sólo debes rellenar el formulario en www.NAW.cl, Ingresando tu nombre, teléfono celular, mail y comuna.
                Así de fácil es ser el primero en recibir las mejores ofertas!!
              </p> -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="modal-bienvenido">
      <div class="container" id="container-modal-wel"><img id="boton-cerrar" src="./images/logos/cerrar.png" alt="" data-target="#modal-bienvenido"/>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" id="box-modal">
          <div class="row" id="box-modal-titulo">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
              <h1 id="title-welcome"><strong>¡Que tal!</strong><img class= "d-flex" id="img-modal-welcome-hand" src="./images/logos/manita.png"></h1>
              <h3 class="display-1">Ya eres Parte de NAW.</h3>
              <hr id="linea">
              <p>En cualquier momento recibirás las mejores ofertas que tenemos  pensadas para ti</p>
              <img class= "img-fluid" id="img-modal-welcome" src="./images/logos/wink.png">
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- <div class="row" id="box-modal-info">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
              <p>
                Desde hoy recibirás ofertas exclusivas de marcas, productos y servicios que recopilaremos especialmente para ti. 
                Gracias y atento porque serás el primero en recibir ofertas.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div> -->
        </div>
        <img class= "img-fluid" id="img-modal-welcome2" src="./images/logos/naw-popup.png">
      </div>
    </div>

      <div class="modal " id="modal-inicio" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" id="modal-init" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content modal-popout-bg">
            <div class="modal-header" id="modal-header-init">
              <img type="button" id="boton-cerrar" src="./images/logos/cerrar.png" alt="" data-target="#modal-inicio"  data-dismiss="modal">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="">
              <div class="row titulo-modal">
                <h3> Hola! Bienvenido a NAW </h3>
              </div>
              <div class="row" id="modal_init_content">
                <p>
                  Somos una plataforma gratuita que ofrece servicios exclusivos de marcar y productos directamente a tu  WhatsApp
                  <br><br>
                  Regístrate y sé el primero en recibir las mejores ofertas.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <img class= "img-fluid" id="img-modal-init" src="./images/logos/naw-popup.png">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>




    <script src="./js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(window).on('load',function(){
          $('#modal-inicio').modal('show');
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Casi no entiendo tu pregunta, según entiendo quieres aumentar el width pero no el height ? Si es así te informo que obviamente es posible pero estarías dañando las dimensiones de tu video lo que haría que se viera mal

Comment: si exacto quiero cambiar el ancho, no me importa si se veria feo jaja pero no me funciona y no se por que

Comment: ¿podrias poner solo el código relevante?

Comment: Explica mejor tu pregunta y ejemplifica de manera más simple tu error

Answer (score 0):

No te funciona por que al aumentar el `width` el elemento siempre va a crecer dependiendo su dimensión, para hacer que el `height` no crezca debes restringirlo

```
info video{
    width: 55%;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 4vw;
    height: 200px /* o la altura que necesites */
}
```

Prueba con esto, espero que te funcione, saludos !

Comment: no se agranda, solo se mueve como si le estuviera dando un marggin

Comment: podrías montar el código html y css por favor en tu pregunta

Comment: listo amigo, a ver que ves tu que yo no :C

Comment: Estas usando sass ?, la idea es que el sitio se pueda ejecutar en la pregunta para poder ver el comportamiento y tener apoyo de la consola

Comment: listo amigo, lo siento habia copia el sass no el css